# What is the prophesied time frame for Ezekiel 37:14?

Tags: ezekiel, chronology, afterlife

> 14And I will put My Spirit within you and you will come to life, and I will place you on your own land. Then you will know that I, the LORD, have spoken and done it,” declares the LORD.’”

I’m supposing that the time of the previous verses are different from this one. They speak merely of “breath”, not “My spirit“.

Comment: In Hebrew, "breath" and "Spirit" are the same word in V6, 9, 10, 14.  Therefore, what is your question?

Comment: The "my spirit" is not referring to the Holy Spirit. It's referring to the human spirit, which belongs to God(and thus He can rightly call it His) because He Himself breathed it into us(Genesis 2:7). The S should not be capitalized; it should be lowercase. For example, Job 34:14 calls **our** breath and spirit(that which sustain US) His(God's), as though it belongs to Him(and it does). "My spirit" does not always refer to the Holy Spirit.

Comment: Hi Steve - I realise it may run against some of your preferred readings, but The Bible Project has a new app out that begins with a word study of רוח, which I think you'd find very helpful in understanding the breadth of the term. Worth a listen through even if you disagree with some of the conclusions.